# REST - how to pull out json nested data from json webservice

Tags: json, rest

Here is part of json data that I need to call to my java project:

{"table":"A","currency":"funt szterling","code":"GBP","rates":[{"no":"1/A/NBP/2012","effectiveDate":"2012-01-02","mid":5.3480}]}

I know how to extract date till the moment "rates" starts, here we have more then 1 value for "rates" itself

```
 JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
 System.out.println("result after Reading JSON Response");

 System.out.println("statusCode- "+myResponse.getString("table"));
 System.out.println("currency- "+myResponse.getString("currency"));
 System.out.println("code- "+myResponse.getString("code"));
 System.out.println("rates: effective Date - "+myResponse.getString("effectiveDate"));// this line is not working
```

How to change last line from my code to be able to get the data under "rates"

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer so...

1. You need to create JSONArray: 
   JSONArray arr = myResponse.getJSONArray("rates");
2. Create a JSONObject and get a index, in this case its only 0 as we have only 1 nesting
   JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
3. Call to print the data same as without nesting:
   System.out.println(obj.getString("no"));